# Problem in calling function in kivy (CODED WITH HELP OF PYTHON) - CALLING FUNCTION IN .kv FILE

Tags: python, kivy

```py
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
#MADE A CLASS FOR MAKING THE GUI
class Main_GUI(App):
    pass
def ind(self):
    print("hi")
kv = Main_GUI()
kv.run()
```

The above is the Python code which i have named **sample.py**.

Below is the **Main_GUI.kv**

```
BoxLayout:
    orientation: "vertical"
    Button:
        text: "Hello"
        on_press: ind()

    Button:
        text: "Btn2"
```

**problem is that the function ***ind*** is not called up**

Please help in rectifying the error.

**ERROR**

NameError: name 'ind' is not defined

Please Intimate me if any errors. I am new to kivy.

Comment: I try changing file name. you have class name & file name same.

Comment: Yes, it was said that if the .kv file name and class name were same, the .kv code would work.<br> classnameApp ---> classname.kv SOURCE: GEEKSFORGEEKS

Answer (score 0):

Your `ind()` method is defined outside of any class. Probably not what you want, but you can access it from within `kv` by adding:

```
#: import ind __main__.ind
```

to the start of your `kv` file.

A better approach is to just move that method inside your `Main_GUI` class:

```
class Main_GUI(App):
    def ind(self):
        print("hi")
```

and access it in `kv` using the `app` keyword:

```
Button:
    text: "Hello"
    on_press: app.ind()
```

The `app` refers to your application instance. See the [documentation](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.lang.html#value-expressions-on-property-expressions-ids-and-reserved-keywords).

Comment: Thank you. I did not know how to call that... The app.ind works perfectly.  Can you please add why app.ind() comes up? Is it because i have inherited the class **App**?